# Difficulty adding two variables

Tags: python

I've been learning python on codeacademy and I wanted to make a program that could help me with my homework and I started with pythagoras a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>=c<sup>2</sup> and it works perfectly on codeacademy but when I try it on the real python program it won't work and it closes before I can read what's wrong.

```
a = input ("what is a")
b = input ("what is b")

a = a*a
b = b*b
c =  a+b

from math import sqrt
c = sqrt (c)

print (c)
```

i know its pretty basic but im still learning also im not sure what version of python code academy is but im pretty sure the python program im useing is 3

Comment: I think this is more readable (and definitely much sorter):
`c = sqrt(a**2 + b**2)`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have a type conververtion problem here. So you need to convert it to an integer:

```
from math import sqrt
a = int(raw_input("what is a: "))
b = int(raw_input("what is b: "))

a = a*a
b = b*b
c = a+b

c = sqrt (c)
print (c)
```

Aslo, to not have to program close before you get to read the output, you would need to run the pythonfile from the terminal.

Comment: thank you all for posting you all helped me with it and it does work now thanks!!

Comment: yeh i know than but i also fixed that with adding another input saying end

Answer (score 0):

You've got a type conversion issue. Cast to an `float` (or a `int`, [here's](http://blog.stillaslife.com/code/tutorials/python-tutorial-3-integers-and-floats/) a little about the difference between the two) and it will all be fine.

```
a = float(input ("what is a"))
b = float(input ("what is b"))
```

You should also look into using your Python interpreter. This is what I got when I tried to step through the code manually:

```
>>> a = input('what is a')
what is a3
>>> a*a # I put 3 in as my number, but it gave me the str value of '3'!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I also recommend `try...except` to help give you better error messages. If you use `while` it will also make it so that you can make sure you have something to work with eg:

```
# Make them keep inputting "a" until they give you something 
# you can actually work with!
while 1:
    try:
        a = float(input ("what is a"))
        break
    except TypeError:
        print('That was not a number! please try again')
```

---

Note: this is not something which would happen in Python 2.x, as input can return an int.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string (type `str`). in order for multiplication to work, you must create an integer (type `int`) from them like this:

```
a = int(input("what is a?"))
b = int(input("what is b?"))
```

or if you want the user to be able to type in decimals, use `float`:

```
a = float(input("what is a?"))
b = float(input("what is b?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2:

```
>>> a=input()
123
>>> a #is an int
123
```

Python 3:

```
>>> a=input()
123
>>> a #is a string
'123'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you run this in the python debugger you'll see what's happening line by line and be able to tell what line is the problem.  I know you are green in Python but learning to use a debugger as soon as possible will make your learning process go so much faster.  Try:

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```